# exact binomial test with power calculation that excludes the lower limit of a 95% CI

Tags: binomial-distribution, exact-test

In a regulatory document I see the following statement and wonder how the sample size of 141 subjects is calculated:

**A sample size of 141 subjects provides 80% power to *exclude* a response rate of 12% using the two-sided 95% exact CI when the response rate of DRUG_NAME is assumed to be 21%.**

Looks like in this binomial test setting, the null is 12% and the alternative is 21%. When I used `exactci` function in R to "back-calculate" the 95% CI (using n=141): `exactci(x=26, n=141, conf.level = 0.95)`, the result is (0.1241324, 0.2583929) which just *excludes* the 12% null from the lower limit. Would like to know how to calculate the 141 sample size given the null/alternative, as well as alpha=0.05 (two-sided) and power (80%).

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the sample size is 141, then 26 or more responses are needed to "rule out" a response rate of 0.12.  In other words, if there are only 25 (or fewer) responses, the lower limit of the 95% confidence interval will be below 0.12, but if there are 26 (or more) responses, then the lower limit will be above 0.12.

Check that:

```
> binom.test(25,141,0.12)

    Exact binomial test

data:  25 and 141
number of successes = 25, number of trials = 141, p-value = 0.05027
alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is not equal to 0.12
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.1181520 0.2505111
sample estimates:
probability of success 
              0.177305 

> binom.test(26,141,0.12)

    Exact binomial test

data:  26 and 141
number of successes = 26, number of trials = 141, p-value = 0.02645
alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is not equal to 0.12
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.1241324 0.2583929
sample estimates:
probability of success 
             0.1843972
```

Now, you can also find that by using the binomial distribution. The probability of observing 25 or more responders is 0.0295 given the true response rate is 0.12. The probability of observing 26 or more responses is 0.017. In other words, the one-sided p-value is under 0.025 when 26 (or more) responses are observed.

```
> 1-pbinom(25-1,141,0.12)
[1] 0.02951398
> 1-pbinom(26-1,141,0.12)
[1] 0.01702271
```

Finally, what is the chance of observing 26 or more responses if the true response rate is 0.21? It should be at least 80% if the document is correct.

```
> 1-pbinom(26-1,141,0.21)
[1] 0.8007429
```

Since this is just barely above 0.8, it is not hard to believe that with any smaller amount of information (n<141), the power would be less than 0.8.

But, all of this just verifies that n=141 is the correct answer. How would you find this from scratch? You have to try different values of n. For each n, find the corresponding number of responses needed to reject H0:p=0.12. Then, find the probability of having that many responses if p=0.21. Keep trying different n's until you find the smallest one that makes the power 80%.

Here's an example for n=100. R says at least 20 responses are needed to make the one-sided p-value less than 0.025 (for testing H0:p=0.12). The probability of 20 or more responses with p=0.21 is about 63.6%. I would start with the sample size using the asymptotic approximation and then use trial and error. If you don't want to use trial and error, you could use the bisection method or something more sophisticated like that to find the n.

```
> which((1-pbinom(c(1:100)-1,100,0.12))<0.025)[1] #smallest num responses needed
[1] 20
> 1-pbinom(19-1,100,0.12) #verify that 19 responses are not enough to reject H0
[1] 0.02817223
> 1-pbinom(20-1,100,0.12) #verify that 20 responses are enough
[1] 0.0147063
> 1-pbinom(20-1,100,0.21) #power
[1] 0.635766
```

Comment: Because of binomial distributions are discrete and there are many styles of confidence intervals, it is not possible to say exactly what sample size $n$ is necessary to achieve the stated goals. But this is a very nice defense (+1) of the claimed $n = 141.$ // I am working on approaches that avoid conflation of confidence intervals and tests and of one vs. two-sided perspectives on the question. So maybe more later.

Answer (score 1):

**Sample sizes for various confidence intervals.**

*Wald CI.* A standard elementary formula for the sample size necessary for a Wald CI of a binomial success probability $p$ to have margin of error $E$ (half width) is
$n = \frac{(z^*)^2p(1-p)}{E^2}.$ For a 95% CI $z^* = 1.96.$ Very roughly, we are
considering $p\approx 0.25,$ and $E\approx 0.055.$ Thus $n \approx 240,$ seems reasonable. This is rough speculation, using a style of CI, coverage probabilities of which have
been much deprecated over the last quarter century, but it is a place
to start. [Computations in R.]

```
1.96^2*.25*.75/.055^2
[1] 238.1157
```

*Jeffries CI.* The Jeffreys style of 95% CI is based on a Bayesian argument, starting with a noninformative prior distribution. It uses quantiles $.025$ and $0.975$ of the distribution $\mathsf{Beta}(x+.5, n-x+.5),$ where $x$ is the number
of successes in $n$ trials. If we contemplate $p \approx 0.17$ and $n \approx 240.$ then we will have $x \approx 41.$ So a typical 95% CI of this style might be $(0.127, 0.222),$ which seems to be of reasonable length and does not include $0.12$  This is rough speculation about a style of interval estimate that has been shown to have reasonably accurate coverage properties.

```
qbeta(c(.025, .975), 41+.5, 240-41+.5)
[1] 0.1272991 0.2222488
```

*Inverting a test.* A much used binomial test of $H_0: p= p_0$ against
$H_a: p \ne p_0$ uses the statistic
$Z = \frac{\hat p - p_0}{\sqrt{p_p(1-p_0)/n}},$
where $\hat p = x/n$ and $Z\stackrel{aprx}{\sim}\mathsf{Norm}(0,1).$
At the 5% level, this test rejects $H_0$ for $|Z|\ge 1.96.$

The Wald interval (originally meant for use with large $n)$ roughly
inverts the test, but estimates the standard error (denominator of $Z)$ as $\sqrt{\hat p(1-\hat p)/n}.$ The *Wilson score interval* arises from an exact inversion of the approximate normal test.
A CI that 'inverts a test' is an interval of hypothetical values $p_0$ for which the data would not have led to rejection.

Power and sample size computations for a binomial tests are available in
many statistical software programs (including a library in R). From Minitab, here is a relevant computation of $n=96$ to achieve 80% power for the approximate normal test of $H_0: p = .12$ against $H_a: p > .12$ at the 5% level for the specific alternative $p_a = 21.$ [In my opinion, the description in the Problem is best suited to a *one-sided* test. For 80% power in a *two-sided test* with $p_0$ and $p_a$ the same distance apart, the required sample size is $n = 119$ (power curve omitted).]

```
Power and Sample Size 

Test for One Proportion

Testing p = 0.12 (versus > 0.12)
α = 0.05

              Sample  Target
Comparison p    Size   Power  Actual Power
        0.21      96     0.8      0.803081
        0.21     138     0.9      0.900327
```

[image]

```
Testing p = 0.12 (versus ≠ 0.12)  # TWO-sided test
α = 0.05

              Sample  Target
Comparison p    Size   Power  Actual Power
        0.21     119     0.8      0.801456
        0.21     166     0.9      0.900293
```

*Note:* Perhaps more later, including exact binomial tests in R.